# DDD: Create one aggregate root within another AR

Tags: domain-driven-design

Suppose that I have 2 aggregate roots (AR) in my domain and invoking some method on the 1st requires access to an instance of the 2nd. **In DDD how and where should retrieval and creation of the 2nd AR happen?**

Here's a contrived example `TravelerEntity` that needs access to a `SuitcaseEntity`. I'm looking for an answer that doesn't pollute the domain layer with infrastructure code.

```
public class TravelerEntity {
    // null if traveler has no suitcase yet.
    private String suitcaseId = ...;
    ...

    // Returns an empty suitcase ready for packing. Caller 
    public SuitcaseEntity startTrip(SuitcaseRepository repo) {
        SuitcaseEntity suitcase;
        if (suitcaseId == null) {
          suitcase = new SuitcaseFactory().create();
          suitcase = repo.save(suitcase);
          suitcaseId = suitcase.getId();
        } else {
          suitcase = repo.findOne(suitcaseId);
        }

        suitcase.emptyContents();

        return suitcase;
    }
}
```

An application layer service handling the start trip request would get the appropriate `SuitcaseRepository` implementation via DI, get the `TravelerEntity` via a `TravelerRepository` implementation and call its `startTrip()` method.

The only alternative I thought of was to move `SuitcaseEntity` management to a domain service, but I don't want to create the suitcase before starting the trip, and I don't want to end up with an anemic `TravelerEntity`.

**I'm a little uncertain about one AR creating and saving another AR. Is this OK since the repo and factory encapsulate specifics about the 2nd AR? Is there a danger I'm missing? Is there a better alternative?**

I'm new enough to DDD to question my thinking on this. And the other questions I found about ARs seem to focus on identifying them properly, not on managing their lifecycles in relation to one another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally `TravelerEntity` wouldn't manipulate a `SuitcaseRepository` because it shouldn't know about an external thing where suitcases are stored, only about its own internals. Instead, it could new up a `SuitCase` and add it to its internal [list of] suitcases. If you wanted that to work with ORMs without specifically adding the suitcase to the repository though, you'd have to store the whole suitcase object in `TravelerEntity.suitcaseList` and not just its ID, which conflicts with the "store references to other AR's as IDs" best practice.

Moreover, `TravelerEntity.startTrip()` returning a suitcase seems a bit artificial and unexplicit and you'll be in trouble if you need to return other entities created by `startTrip()`. So a good solution could be to have `TravelerEntity` emit a `SuitcaseAdded` event with the suitcase data in it once it has added the suitcase to its list. An application service could subscribe to the event, add the suitcase to `SuitcaseRepository` and commit the transaction, effectively saving both the new suitcase and the modified traveler to the database.

Alternatively, you could place `startTrip()` in a Domain Service instead of an Entity. There it might be more legit to use `SuitcaseRepository` since a domain service is allowed know about multiple domain entities and the overall domain process going on.

Comment: Your suggestion to use domain events to signal domain services to save created objects really cleared this up for me. Thanks!

Comment: The signalled services would be application services, not domain services ;) Domain services are not in control of the overarching Unit of Work and can't commit a transaction. Application services are usually the ones that will orchestrate calls to domain objects, repositories and define unit of work start and end.

Comment: A much recommended article about all that : http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/14/services-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/

Comment: Thanks for clarifying re domain/application services. Funny enough I read that article in the past few weeks of learning DDD, but until hitting this point I don't think I was ready to apply it. It's now quite timely. :)

Comment: @KevinCondon Saving entities in a event handler works only when using event sourcing. An event contains flattened entity data, therefore a repository would need to know with events for both saving/loading the entity. Passing the entire entity in an event is bad design, because an event is always a dto which can cross boundaries and might need serialization.

Comment: @MikeSW I was thinking about using a domain entity factory interface, realized in the application layer, and passed to the other entity that needed to do the creation. Since the factory would be realized in the application layer, it could have access to the repository and save the newly created object. So is there some reason that an application layer factory should not know about repositories?

Comment: @KevinCondon Don't complicate your life, really... Things are simple and straightforward: service creates entity, then sends it to the repository, then sends the entity generated domain events to a service bus for publishing. A factory for domain entities needs some very specialized use cases and I don't remember last time when I needed one. Just keep it simple

Comment: @MikeSW Thing is my real domain has an aggregate root that has logic determining when/if 2 other aggregate roots should be created. If I create beforehand, they might not be needed. If I move that logic to the service, the domain becomes anemic. I could converge to one aggregate, but the concerns and lifecycles of the aggregates suggest keeping them as references. I shudder to think that an anemic domain looks so inviting.

Comment: I don't know your domain, but I don't think your AR should have that responsibility. That logic should be a domain service. Actually I believe that you might have an improper modelling problem and your ARs do too much. Aggregates represent concepts and services are use cases of those concepts. `StartTrip` doesn't sound like a behaviour which defines the Traveler concept. DDD is hard because it's tricky and many devs come up with great answers for the wrong questions.

Comment: @MikeSW My real domain is completely unrelated to my contrived domain example, but my example could have been better. I'm confident that I've identified the right ARs, so I'm going to refactor the AR logic to boolean methods that the service can use to manage AR creation and storage. So the service would just make a few high-level decisions, which won't eviscerate the domain objects all that much. Your well explained comments have helped me work thorough this. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeSW There's actually a school of thought that recommends spawning AR's from other AR's -- http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/

Comment: I know about Udi's post, however we can't force everything into one approach.

Answer (score 0):

First of all persistence is not domain's job so i would get rid of all the repositories from the domain models and create a service that would use them.

Second of all you should rethink your design. Why a StartTrip method of a Traveller should return a SuitCase?

A Traveller either has or hasn't a suitcase. Once you have retrieved the Traveller you should already have their SuitCases too.

```
public class StartTripService {
     public void StartTrip(int travellerId) {
         var traveller = travellerRepo.Get(travellerId);
         traveller.StartTrip();
     }
}
```

Comment: There seems to be disagreement about repository usage in the domain. See http://evan.bottch.com/2007/12/06/factory-and-repository-in-the-domain/, but yeah _saving_ to persistence in a domain object feels wrong. Assume that my traveler might not own a suitcase and that `startTrip()` will fail if he has a calendar conflict, so he wouldn't want to buy a suitcase if the method fails. So I'd need to refactor the domain so that a service could gather and save repository objects as needed, right?

Comment: And it dawns on me that refactoring too much to services results in an anemic domain. That's the challenge in my real domain that the traveler example is trying to illustrate.

Comment: The services just use the domain methods and combine them together to accomplish a task. On the other hand if the domain entity really cannot do many things you shouldn't add methods there just to add them. It is really a design matter.